# Difficulty with GCSE A453 Programming Task 3

Tags: python, sorting

Over the past few days, I have been attempting to code a solution to Task 3 of the A453 Computing section. Essentially, I am aiming to produce a program that takes data from members of a class that have participated in a maths quiz (that is situated over three text files, as the exam specification states that participants in the hypothetical quiz must be from a "Class 1" "Class 2", or "Class 3")and then sorts it, according to the user's input, in one of the two following ways:

- In alphabetical order with each student's (in the appropriate class) highest score for the tests.
- By the highest score achieved by each student in that class, from highest to lowest.

Here is the code that I have written up so far:

```
def highest_score_first():
    names_with_scores_list = []
    ScoresFirstList = []
    AlreadySeenList = []

    for line in file:
        names_with_scores_list.append(line.strip())

    for row in names_with_scores_list:
        nameString = row[0: row.index(', ') ]
        scoreString = row[row.index(', ')+2 : len(row)]
        scoresFirstString = scoreString+","+nameString
        #print(scoresFirstString)
        ScoresFirstList.append(scoresFirstString)

    ScoresFirstList.sort(reverse = True)

    for row in ScoresFirstList:       
        nameString = row[row.index(',') : len(row)]    
        if nameString not in AlreadySeenList:
            print(row)
            AlreadySeenList.append(nameString)

def alphabetical():
    names_with_scores_list = []
    NamesFirstList = []
    AlreadySeenList = []

    for line in file:
        names_with_scores_list.append(line.strip())

    for row in names_with_scores_list:
        nameString = row[0: row.index(', ') ]
        scoreString = row[row.index(', ')+2 : len(row)]
        NamesFirstString = nameString+","+scoreString
        NamesFirstList.append(NamesFirstString)



    NamesFirstList.sort()





    for row in NamesFirstList:
        nameString = row[0: row.index(',') ]
        if nameString not in AlreadySeenList:
            print (row)
            AlreadySeenList.append(nameString)


# main code here

chosen_class = input("Which class would you like to view - one, two or three?")
if chosen_class == "one":
    file = open("classonescore.txt","r")
elif chosen_class == "two":
    file = open("classtwoscore.txt","r")
elif chosen_class == "three":
    file = open("classthreescore.txt","r")
else:
    print("Unfortunately, you have entered an invalid class name. ")



function = input("How would you like to sort the data - alphabetically or by highest score? Choose A or H")
if function.upper() == "H":
    highest_score_first()
elif function.upper() == "A":
    alphabetical()
```

Essentially, the problem with the code is that, when the user wants the data for a class to be sorted alphabetically (in terms of highest score), only the lowest score for each student, as well as his name, is generated.

For instance, whilst data from Class 1 is written into the text file as follows:

Chris, 08
Clive, 09
Will, 04
Harry, 10
Ahmed, 08
Geoff, 06
Amy, 04
Vennu, 10
Vennu, 07
Amy, 06
Ahmed, 09
Geoff, 04
Harry, 07
Will, 06
Clive, 10
Chris, 10

It is displayed upon running the program (when the user wants scores to be generated using "alphabetical") as:

Ahmed,08
Amy,04
Chris,08
Clive,09
Geoff,04
Harry,07
Vennu,07
Will,04

Ideally, it should be generated as follows:

Ahmed, 09
Amy, 06
Chris, 10
Clive, 10
Geoff, 06
Harry, 10
Vennu, 10
Will, 06

Unfortunately, I am unable to contact my teacher, so any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: It may help if you split the list of combined names and scores into pairs of [name, score].  Then you can sort by the score.  Alternatively, use the 'score name' list you generated in the `highest_score` function to sort, discard the low scores then recombine the rows as 'name score' and print.